# How do we create a link to an Asana workspace

Tags: asana

Asana appears to have the following link structure:

https://app.asana.com/A/B/C

How would you build a link to a workspace assuming I have the workspace Id. E.g. a link to to My Tasks in a specific workspace.

These work for other uses, but could not figure it out for workspaces

- open a task: https://app.asana.com/0/0/task-id
- open a project: https://app.asana.com/0/project-id/project-id
- open a tag: https://app.asana.com/0/tag-id/tag-id

Thanks

Comment: Found this link in the Asana documentation: http://app.asana.com/-/account_api. Could there be some link shortcuts available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really a page that *just* represents the workspace, and there's no shortcut for "the current viewer's My Tasks in Workspace X". So I'm afraid the answer is "we don't have that right now". :-/